# Can Liquid Nails cover a small hole

Tags: vinyl-flooring, patch

I'm installing some vinyl plank flooring. In one spot where a transition piece is going to go, there is a small hole that will expand under the vinyl. The transition piece is going to be installed with Liquid Nails or J.B. Weld.

[image]

Can I just fill in the hole with Liquid Nails/JB Weld or do I need to apply some type of patch first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are cementitious floor patches made for this purpose that will give you better results. Liquid Nails, indispensable though it may be, doesn't really harden enough to do a patch job like this. Here's a video of a guy patching a floor that's pretty thorough.[Floor patch.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVHw05-pkZ8)

Answer (score 0):

For such a small hole, how about spackle?